# API to list activity log in Urban Airship

Tags: php, curl, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm using PHP with CURL to send push notification by using API of Urban Airship to android and ios devices for more than hundred apps. Now I want to list activity logs like Airship panel but could not find any suitable API like we use for push `'/api/push'` and for list schedule `'api/schedules'` so could anyone please suggest api name to list activity log? or any alternative solution for this?